# How to add rel attribute based on href filename

Tags: jquery

I have an ASP search script that returns results mainly of PDFs and some other documents. In the bulk of the site I use a jQuery plugin called clueTip (by Karl Swedberg) that creates a tooltip when the user hovers over certain links. The content of these links is pulled by ajax from an html file defined in the rel attribute of the link:

```
<a href="../../example.pdf" class="tips" rel="../../tooltips/example.html>
```

When a user does a search I want to be able to dynamically add these tooltips to PDFs from one certain location - `../../technicalarticles`. So I need to:

1. Find any returned PDFs that are in `../../technicalarticles` and add `class="tips"` to the link
2. From those PDFs I need to extract the relevant file name (everything from the last `/` to the file extension)
3. Append that file name to the `rel` attribute

Below is my jQuery code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".results a").each(function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("technicalarticles") >= 0)
    // if statement to find the right pdfs
    { 
        var firstpos = location.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1; // finds the position of the last / and adds 1
        var lastpos = location.href.lastIndexOf('.')-1; // finds the position of the last . and subtracts 1
        var filename = location.href.substr(firstpos, lastpos); // filename should now have eveything from the last / to the file extension

        $(this).attr('rel', ".data/tooltips/" + filename + ".html"); // adds the rel string to the link
        $(this).addClass('tips'); // adds the class 'tips' to the link
    }
} );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

window.location is url of current page. You need to use context of your jQuery method $(this) - current proccessed link. Try to get/set it attributes by .attr() like this

```
var target = $(this);
someUrlPath = /here get part of url/
target.attr('rel', target.attr('rel') + someUrlPath);
```

But I think a better practice is use ASP for filling rel parameter if it's possible.